# Serve website from different directory based on URL string parameter

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite, apache2, url-routing, litespeed

I would like to learn if I can serve the website from 2 different versions according to URL string parameters.

**Example:**

- I have two installs on my server: `example.com/website-1/` and `example.com/website-2/`
- if end-user visits `example.com/main/?showads=yes` —> serve website from `example.com/website-1/`
- İf end-user visits domain `example.com/main/` —> serve website from `example.com/website-2/`

**Note:** this is not a redirection question, I just want to serve with the same URL.

**p.s.** I'm running a WordPress website on an Apache server.

I'm open to any solution via PHP, WordPress, or Apache (`.htaccess`) config.

Comment: You've tagged your question "apache2" _and_ "litespeed" - it can't be both?

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the necessary internal rewrite at the top of your root `.htaccess` file. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^showads=yes$
RewriteRule ^main/$ /website-1/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^main/$ /website-2/index.php [L]
```

If the user requests `/main/?showads=yes` (exactly as stated) then the request is routed to the WordPress install in `/website-1/` and if the user requests `/main/` (exactly - no query string) then the request is routed to the WP install in `/website-2/`. (NB: You should rewrite directly to `index.php`, rather than let mod_dir issue a secondary internal subrequest.)

HOWEVER, since this is WordPress, WP itself also needs to be configured to accept requests to `/main/` in both of the websites (ie. this must be a valid URL in WP), otherwise, WP will trigger a 404.

You may consider asking this question over on the [WordPress stack](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) for more assistance with the WP side of this.